# jQuery copy content from one div into another

Tags: jquery, append, clone, copy-paste

Working on my portfoilio script I'm now at the point where I want to copy the invisible `<p>`-content from one div into another one, but it doesn't work - any ideas how to solve this? Tried the

```
.clone()
```

action, but it did not work until now.

Have a look [AT MY FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mleyendecker/632Fw/38/)

I want to copy inside the triggered .projecttile div into the #moreinfo div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a separate div within your #moreinfo block, or otherwise when you copy the hidden details you will erase your [X] close button.  I'm not sure whether you are trying to preserve the original dummy image or copy it over with the clicked one, but you can copy the hidden text with something like this (I'm using `html` instead of `text` in case you have markup in there).

```
$('#details').html($(this).parent().find('p').html());
```

I would also maybe add a class to the hidden `<p>` values and reference it by that, in case you wanted more than one `<p>` tag in there.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dshell/8FYrs/

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found a solution like this: 


                $(this).nextAll().slice(0, 2).appendTo( "#moreinfo" );

Now the problem I have: when I closed the .moreinfo div the appended content stays there - what do I need to add to my closing action to remove the content? 

// Updated my jsfiddle

Comment: Well, that's why I suggested adding a new element to hold your content explicitly.  With my fiddle you could just do `$('#details').empty()` and it would be deleted.  With yours you could add a class to the object you're appending with `$(this).nextAll().slice(0,2).addClass("appended").appendTo("#moreinfo");`, and then do something like `$(".appended").remove();`

Comment: Yeah, great! Did what you told me and it works great - thank you!

May I ask two questions: 1) Why am I not able to find both, the h1 and the p element? And 2) Is there a way to keep them styled as h1 and p when moved into the details div?

Comment: If you're wanting to move the `img` tag then you could copy the whole `div.portfoliotile` with the `html(...)` call - this will preserve the `h1` and `p` tags where `.text(...)` will not.  If you don't want to copy the image then I would group the `p` and `h1` tags together under a new `div` and copy that instead.

Comment: Boom! There we go - thanks man! Now everything I need to do is make it smooth so that it's fading in and out. What I just noticed: is there a smart way to remove the .darken class from a .projecttile when another .projecttile is active?

Comment: Happy to help!  I would probably just first remove it from *everybody* with a `$('.darken').removeClass("darken");` and then explicitly add it to the one you want to have it.

Comment: What do you mean with "remove it from everybody" ?

Comment: The `$('.darken')` selector will find all objects that have that class applied to them, and them remove it from them all. So it's not actually *everybody*, but *everybody with this class*.  You could optionally select only projecttiles with the class by combining the classes in the selector with `$('.projecttile.darken')`

Comment: Still not sure if you mean it like this, but these lines solved the problem: $('.dark').removeClass('dark');
                $(this).parent().addClass('dark');

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was saying.  I didn't go back and look at the literal class name - you called it ".darken" above, so that's what I used in my response.  :)

Comment: yeah, was a typo. 
Thank you very, very much! Will have a look at how to make everything more 'smooth' now and then I'm ready to work with it. What would you recommend to move down the container-div containing the projecttiles when the moreinfo-div is active?

I thought about first calculating the height of the .moreinfo-div, add a 0px div before the container and increase it's height to the .moreinfo's height.

Answer (score 3):

You can use html() method to copy content inside html element & set it.

e.g.

```
var data = $('source_div').html();
$('target_div').html(data);
```